# How to Capture a specific output of a function in Powershell when theres more then 2 Output Types in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

i am working on a onboarding Script in MSPS. When i use SomeCertainCommand

> SomeCommand $CSV[0] | Out-File SomeFilePath

-> and write the Output in a File, i Get following Output:

> failed to get console mode for stdout: The handle is invalid.
>
> failed to get console mode for stdout: The handle is invalid.
>
> ID           Name             Email             Type
>
> actual ID    actual Name     actual Email     actual Type

---

i would like to Capture just the actual ID because i have to do additional work with it. Does anyone have an Idea how to realize this?

UPDATE

---

So if i use the Command:

> someCommand $CSV[0] | Select-Object -Property ID | out-file SomeFilePath

-> My Outputfile Containts:

> Id
>
> --

But what i need is not the header... I need the actual ID

Comment: Try `$CSV[0].Id` and why use `Out-File` at all when you can directly use all properties from the CSV like this?

Comment: Use `ForEach-Object` instead of `Select-Object` if you want to expand a single property only: `someCommand $CSV[0] | ForEach-Object ID | out-file SomeFilePath`